# vscode could not open radian (Linux, Manjaro)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Open a R script and click `Run Source` then I get

```
The terminal process "/home/xxx/miniconda3/bin/radiant ''" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

and a massage in terminal window

```py
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "home/xxx/miniconda3/bin/radian", line 8, in <module>
    sys. exit(main())
  File "home/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python.7/site-packages/radian/init.py", line 44, in main
    r_home = Rhome()
  FIle "home/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python.7/site-packages/rchitect/utils.py", line 84, in Rhome
    raise RuntimeError ("Cannot determine R HOME.")
RuntimeError: Cannot determine R HOME.
```

But, in system terminal I can use radiant and find R HOME.

I have tried reinstall vscode and all extentions, it doesn't work.

And after I read massage in terminal and read code in `~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rchitect/utils.py`

I add

```sh
export R_HOME="/home/xxx/miniconda3/bin/R"
```

in my `.zshrc`. But it doesn't work.

And in my environment value there is only one value

```sh
RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/home/xxx/miniconda3/bin/R
```

- Vscode version is `1.47.1`, install by `yay -Sy community/code`
- vscode extention `ikuyadeu.r` version is `1.4.3`
- vscode extention `reditorsupport.r-lsp` version is `0.1.6`
- zsh version is `5.8 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- R version is `4.0.2 (2020-06-22)` install by `conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.0`
- radian version is `0.5.8`
- python version is `3.7.7`

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for @randy3k help.

Across to read [github page](https://github.com/randy3k/radian#how-to-switch-to-a-different-r-or-specify-the-version-of-r), I find a way to solve it.

I add a option in my vscode settings.

```
  "r.rterm.option": ["--r-binary=/home/xxx/miniconda3/bin/R"],
```

Comment: This also works if you go to the Settings GUI on VSCode and search for "rterm: Option"

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **windows**:

1. In R Studio, run `R.home()` and copy output.
2. In a terminal (e.g. powershell), run: `$env:R_HOME='xxx'` where you replace xxx with what you have copied in 1.