# Installing R for VSCode issues (R LSP)

Tags: r, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use Visual Studio for R for the first time, and am having a hard time starting.
I have installed VSCode as a binary on my Windows machine (needed because of corporate machine).
My R executables are in my documents folder (also because I'm on a corporate machine).
I have downloaded `R` and `R Debugger` extensions in VSCode. *I could not find `R LSP Client`, even though tutorials from 2020 showed that it was necessary.
I have installed languageserver in my R client, and have also done pip install radian.

My settings.json looks like this:

```
"r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\x64\\R.exe",
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\Scripts\\radian.exe", 
"r.lsp.debug": true,
"r.lsp.diagnostics": true,
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-save",
        "--no-restore",
        "--r-binary=C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\x64\\R.exe"
    ]
```

Somehow each time I execute code, it shows:

```
[Running] Rscript "c:\Users\XXXX\code\R\tempCodeRunnerFile.R"
'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?
This is my first time using VSCode, and I've tried looking across multiple stack overflow questions and URLs to no avail.
Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Note--see comments in solution, but **I ended up copying radian.exe into a new folder and resetting the path there in the json file**. And importantly, in VSCode, you cannot use Ctrl+Alt+N for R. You must use Alt+Enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: Ensure R is setup right:

In your JSON settings, change `r.rpath.windows` and `--r-binary` from

`"C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\x64\\R.exe"`

to

`"C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\R.exe"`

(That is, drop the `\\x64`--and don't worry, VSCode should still open 64-bit R even with these changes).

**Step 2**: Fix the issue of running an R Script from the Editor:

In your JSON settings, add the following line:

```
 "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
```

**Step 3**: Fix the Radian path

Double check your path location for Radian under `r.rterm.windows`. Try changing it to:

`"C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\radian.exe"`

After that, save the changes and then restart VSCode.

Comment: Hi coip, thanks for this. I have tried replacing the binary string. It still fails to execute. I also looked at radian. If i do `pip install radian` after `cmd` in windows, it gives me, "C:\Users\XXXX>pip install radian
Requirement already satisfied: radian in c:\users\XXXXXX\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (0.5.13)" Should I be doing something different?

Comment: When you say it fails to execute, are you referring just to running a .R script from the editor to the terminal? I assume you can use R in the VSCode terminal just fine otherwise? When you type `radian` into the Powershell terminal in VSCode, does it switch to Radian? Can you launch the Radian.exe from that location independently (i.e. outside of VSCode)?

Comment: yes, from the editor to the terminal. when I type in radian into the VSCode terminal, it says "r : The term 'radian' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: And if I just type in that string for Radian.exe in the command line (outside VSCode), then it gives. 
    r_home = Rhome()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\rchitect\utils.py", line 85, in Rhome
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot determine R HOME.")
RuntimeError: Cannot determine R HOME.

Comment: If I search cannot determine R HOME in stackoverflow, I get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089647/vscode-could-not-open-radian-linux-manjaro. the solution of which I've already done.

Comment: When you boot up VSCode and see the terminal window, to the right it should say the default terminal (usually Powershell), and to the right of that is a + sign and a drop-down arrow. When you click on the drop-down arrow, what terminal options are listed?

Comment: powershell, git bash, command prompt, javascript debug, r terminal, split terminal

Comment: Okay, and when you click on R terminal there, an R terminal opens up and you can do R things like `head(mtcars)`, right? If so, R is set up right. Next step is to solve the issue of the script not running from the editor. And after that, fix Radian. See my updated answer above and let me know if that fixes your issues or not.

Comment: Hi coip, thanks for the help. yes, `head(mtcars)` works, but somehow even after those changes, I'm seeing the same error.

Comment: If you select R from the terminal dropdown menu so that an R terminal opens up and becomes the active terminal, and then you open a new editor file (Ctrl + N or File > New File), and then in that new file you type `head(mtcars)` and then click on that line and hit Alt+Enter, what error message do you get?

Comment: so is this actually the way it is meant to be run? I cannot do Ctrl+alt+N?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ctrl+Alt+N, as I always use Alt+Enter to run a line of code and Ctrl+Shift+S to source the whole script (there's also a right-facing arrow on the top right of the VSCode editor you can click); but, you should be able to customize your VSCode keyboard shortcuts via the Command Palette: `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. As for Radian, did you try another path like the one I suggested in my revised answer? If so, when you select the R terminal, does it look like R (e.g. >) or Radian (e.g. r$>)?

Comment: I see. I ended up copying radian.exe into a new folder and resetting the path there in the json file. it looks like r$>